# How to filter the data from the list and remove the existing room from the data in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
data = [{
 id: "txv3vvBr8KYB",
 name: "room 1"
},{
 id: "txv3vvBr8KJB",
 name: "room 2"
},{
 id: "txv3vvBr8K",
 name: "room 4"
},{
 id: "txv3vvBr8LKP",
 name: "room 3"
},{
 id: "txv3vvBr8LDS",
 name: "room 5"
}]

roomList = [
 {
      room: {
        code: "r001",
        id: "txv3vvBr8KYB",
        name: "room 1",
        status: "FULL"
      }
    },
 {
      room: {
        code: "r002",
        id: "txv3vvBr8KJB",
        name: "room 2",
        status: "FULL"
      }
    },
 {
      room: {
        code: "r003",
        id: "txv3vvBr8LKP",
        name: "room 3",
        status: "FULL"
      }
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do here is to filter the data from the roomList and remove the item from data when they are the same ids.

the expected output should be like this:

```
data = [{
     id: "txv3vvBr8K",
     name: "room 4"
    }{
     id: "txv3vvBr8LDS",
     name: "room 5"
    }]
```

I tried to use a filter and map.

```
this.data.filter((x: any) => this.roomList.map((y: any) => y['room']['id] === x['id']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably best to first [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the room IDs to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and then [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) based on that:

```
const ids = roomList.reduce((a, {room: {id}}) => (a.add(id), a), new Set());
const result = data.filter(({id}) => !ids.has(id));
```

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  id: "txv3vvBr8KYB",
  name: "room 1"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8KJB",
  name: "room 2"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8K",
  name: "room 4"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8LKP",
  name: "room 3"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8LDS",
  name: "room 5"
}];

const roomList = [{
    room: {
      code: "r001",
      id: "txv3vvBr8KYB",
      name: "room 1",
      status: "FULL"
    }
  },
  {
    room: {
      code: "r002",
      id: "txv3vvBr8KJB",
      name: "room 2",
      status: "FULL"
    }
  },
  {
    room: {
      code: "r003",
      id: "txv3vvBr8LKP",
      name: "room 3",
      status: "FULL"
    }
  }
];

const ids = roomList.reduce((a, {room: {id}}) => (a.add(id), a), new Set());
const result = data.filter(({id}) => !ids.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

---

Alternatively, if you really want to do it in a one-liner and performance is not that big of an issue, you can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const result = data.filter(({id}) => !roomList.some(({room}) => room.id === id));
```

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  id: "txv3vvBr8KYB",
  name: "room 1"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8KJB",
  name: "room 2"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8K",
  name: "room 4"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8LKP",
  name: "room 3"
}, {
  id: "txv3vvBr8LDS",
  name: "room 5"
}];

const roomList = [{
    room: {
      code: "r001",
      id: "txv3vvBr8KYB",
      name: "room 1",
      status: "FULL"
    }
  },
  {
    room: {
      code: "r002",
      id: "txv3vvBr8KJB",
      name: "room 2",
      status: "FULL"
    }
  },
  {
    room: {
      code: "r003",
      id: "txv3vvBr8LKP",
      name: "room 3",
      status: "FULL"
    }
  }
];

const result = data.filter(({id}) => !roomList.some(({room}) => room.id === id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.data = this.data.filter(item => item !== data_item);
```

Reference:https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/remove+element+from+list+angular+8